# How to select 1st div with same classname but different conditions using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver-python

New to Python Selenium and I want to select the 3rd:

```
<div class = "inner-TPBYkbxL" ...>
```

from the below 3 `<div>` classes with the same class name. I'm not sure what is meant by

```
<... "data-is-fake-main-panel" =  "true" or "false">
```

after

```
<div class = "inner-TPBYkbxL" ...>
```

Snapshot:

[Div Class Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFLe4.png)

How should I structure my selenium web driver script?
I've tried the below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-TPBYkbxL']").click()
```

But it returned:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: It turns out that the element I need to select is <div class = "inner-TPBYkbxL fake-TPBYkbxL" data-is-fake-main-panel="true"> but it also has an element with the exact same name below

Answer (score 0):

Generally `<div>` elements aren't interactable barring some exceptational conditions. Hence when you invoke `click()` on the `<div>` element identified by:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-TPBYkbxL']")
```

You are facing:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

---

### This usecase

Not that super clear why you would click a `<div>` element. However to identify the the element:

```
<div class = "inner-TPBYkbxL" data-is-fake-main-panel="false">
```

you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div,inner-TPBYkbxL[data-is-fake-main-panel='false']")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='inner-TPBYkbxL' and @data-is-fake-main-panel='false']")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I actually want to use selenium to click on the "down arrow" button (which will launch a drop-down menu) as shown in the top left area of the screenshot above. Therefore I believe I would need to select all the previous div classes first before I can actually perform the click() on the <span class = "icon-XIHzWm6B"> (2nd element from the bottom of the screenshot)? FYI - I've been getting the "element not interactable" error message if I do a direct click() via XPATH for <span class = "icon-XIHzWm6B">

Comment: Possibly you are correct and it seems like a seperate issue. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: Hi @undetected-selenium, could you kindly take a look at a related question here in the case of selecting the 1st div class with the 2nd one having the same name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75689880/how-to-select-the-1st-div-class-with-two-div-classes-with-the-same-name